# Angular 5 how to get file name from input with type = file

Tags: angular, image, input, ngmodel

I know there are simmilar questions but none cover the method for Angular 5 or at least not in a way that I understand it.

For my image upload system I need to know if a picture is attached to the input tag and what name the file has. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input 
  type="file" 
  [(ngModel)]="currentInput"
  (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
>
```

Angular:

```
export class ImageUpload {
    currentInput;

    onFileSelected(event) {
        console.log(this.currentInput);
    }
}
```

No matter if there is a file attached or not the value in "currentInput" is always undefined. How does this work with input when the type is equal to "file"?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried your code, works fine for me, Check this out => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kl2y1z

Comment: well in my example I get undefined..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this below  way

```
onFileSelected(event) {
 if(event.target.files.length > 0) 
  {
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@ramesh-rajendran's answer is good. If you want the TypeScript solution:

```
onFileSelected(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.files && target.files.length > 0) {
        console.log(target.files[0].name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to input field, it is a requirement: https://angular.io/guide/forms#!#ngModel. Also, you have defined the function outside of class. function and property both need to be inside a class.

**Update:** Data binding not supported with file input types. It need to be done using pure javascript.

```
<input 
  type="file" 
  name = "currentInput"
  [(ngModel)]="currentInput"
  (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
>

export class ImageUpload {
  currentInput:any;
  onFileSelected(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files);
    this.currentInput = event.target.files; 
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Thanks for the update but that was just a typo on my behalf, your solution still doesn't do anything

Comment: Yes data binding not supported with file input types. It need to be done using pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//In your component, create a function that emits an event on file selected
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    const file: File = event[0];
    console.log(file);
}
```

```html
// In your html, attach the function to the input tag like so
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try the code below. It uses event emitter which listens to input changes and returns the file object, along with its metadata. Give it a try. What I like is that you don't need an external library.

```js
//In your component, create a function that emits an event on file selected
import {Component, OnInit, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    const file: File = event[0];
    console.log(file);
}
```

```html
// In your html, attach the function to the input tag like so
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

Comment: The event emitted from (change) handled is NOT of type [File[]] - above code doesn't output correct file in the log